# Cucumber print some variables?

Tags: java, cucumber

I am a .net developer and knows almost 0 to Cucumber or close to 0 about Java now (after 20 years not using it).

However, I was just given a Cucumber project used by other team (that team doesn't have java developer any more and no intention to hire any in future).

I can understand what Cucumber is doing, but there are some details I couldn't get.

For example, for this feature

```
@ChargesAPI
 Scenario Outline: ChargesAPI project - Compare ChargesV2 VS ChargesV3 POST JSON Message
    Given As a user i want to compare sheet ChargesAPI ChargesV2VsChargesV3 POST JSON output Message
    When I POST given first <Iteration> URL DP:URI_1 and Json body DP:JSON_Message_1 content
    And I POST given second <Iteration> URL DP:URI_2 and Json body DP:JSON_Message_2 content
    Then I Compare both Output_Mess1 Output_Mess2 Output Message <Iteration>
  Examples:
 |Iteration|   
|1|
|2|
|3|
|4|
|5|
|6|
|7|
|8|
|9|
|10|
|11|
|12|
|13|
|14|
|15|
```

looks like cucumber somehow will call our custom java code (maybe because it is defined in the cucumber.json file?)

```
public class POSTJSON_Steps {

    private ActionContainer actcontainer;

    public POSTJSON_Steps(ActionContainer actcontainer) {
        this.actcontainer = actcontainer;
    }

    private String First_Mess;
    private String Second_Mess;

    @When("^I POST given first (.*) URL (.*) and Json body (.*) content")
    public void I_POST_first_URL_and_JsonBody_content(int Itr,String strURI, String JSON) throws Exception {

        First_Mess = actcontainer.postmethods.ThunderPostMethod(Itr,strURI,JSON);
    }

    @And("^I POST given second (.*) URL (.*) and Json body (.*) content")
    public void I_POST_second_URL_and_JsonBody_content(int Itr,String strURI, String JSON) throws Exception {
        Second_Mess = actcontainer.postmethods.ThunderPostMethod(Itr,strURI,JSON);

    }

    @Then("^I Compare both (.*) (.*) Output Message (.*)$")
    public void I_Compare_QA_VS_Staging_Output_Message(String strFstJSON, String strSndJSON,int Itr) throws Exception {

        actcontainer.storedata.StoreJSONMessAsJson(Itr,strFstJSON,strSndJSON, First_Mess,Second_Mess);   
        actcontainer.comparedata.CompareJSONOutput(Itr,First_Mess, Second_Mess);    
    }

}
```

I wanted to print out parameter detail in out PostMethods.java (basically try to print some debugging info)

```
public class POSTMethods {

    public String ThunderPostMethod(int itr,String strURL, String JSONBody) throws Exception {

        String strContent = null;
        strContent = RESTClient.POSTREQUEST(itr, strURL, JSONBody, "Authorization/Bearer "+TokenGenerate.AuthToken());

    System.out.println("strContent:"+strContent);
    System.out.println("strURL:"+strURL);
    System.out.println("JSONBody:"+JSONBody);

        strContent = PostJSONSorting.POST_JSONValue(strContent,itr,strURL, JSONBody);
        return strContent;
    }

}
```

However, the print always return this:
**strURL:DP:URI_1 JSONBody:DP:JSON_Message_1**

So looks like cucumber has some way to replace DP:URI_1 and DP:JSON_Message_1 to the real url and message?

I just want to find a way to print out the url and message this code is sending, is there a way?

Comment: its better to use karate is if you need to pay around with API https://github.com/intuit/karate

Comment: this is not really a related comment I would say